# Why the WFS point is not shown to the correct location after a WFS Update request

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, wfs, wfs-t

I've been working on the implementation of an **edit the position of a point** functionality.
I use leaflet and geoserver and give the possibility to the user to change the location of a point.
It works as expected but its a bit slow. As you can see in the image, although the WMS point has moved correctly, the WFS point is still in the old position. It takes some time (approx. one minute) in order to be displayed correctly.

Any ideas why this is happening?

[image]

**EDIT**

This is how I implement the edit. I actually send a POST request using Python Requests library. The XML of the POST request looks like this:

```
<wfs:Transaction service="WFS" version="1.1.0"
  xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
  xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
 <wfs:Update typeName="geonode:{{ layer_name }}">
  <wfs:Property>
   <wfs:Name>the_geom</wfs:Name>
    <wfs:Value>
     <gml:Point>
       <gml:pos>{{ coords }}</gml:pos>
     </gml:Point>
    </wfs:Value>
  </wfs:Property>
 <ogc:Filter>
   <ogc:FeatureId fid="{{ coords }}"/>
  </ogc:Filter>
 </wfs:Update>
</wfs:Transaction>
```

Comment: Your client might cache it, have you tried requesting the point from another "clean" client? QGIS can be useful for testing or even straight tools like the manual HTTP request via your browser, wget or curl or maybe OGR.

Comment: Yes you must be right. Its related with browser caching. How do you deal with this issue? Refreshing the cache manually is a no go.

Comment: Can you show how you are implementing the edit?

Comment: @BradHards I have edited my question.

Comment: How do you handle the refresh? Or, what do you do where you do not get the fresh data instead of the stale cache?

Comment: I use map.invalidateSize(); leaflet function to redraw map. Usually I get the fresh data after a couple of minutes. I tried to hard refresh the browser (with developers tool activated) and it worked properly. So it is really a caching issue. The question now is how to solve it. I am trying to find if there is a cache parameter, I can indlude in the WFS request.

Comment: That would be easier if you show the client side code. The WFS-T request XML is really about changing the server state, and can't change the render side on the client.